# C++ cout string print its memory value

Tags: c++, string, cout

I am trying to create a keygen to some reversing challenges around there.
I decided to try to code it in a language that I don't know well, c++

I not sure how to use pointers yet, but I thing that I implemented the algorithm well without them. the only problem is that I print the answer I get it's memory location instead all the string.

```
char decrypt(char c, int position);
int main(){

    cout << "Enter username:" << endl;
    string username;
    string answer[20] = "";
    cin >> username;
    for (int i = username.length(); i > 0; i--){
        answer[username.length() - i] = decrypt(username[i-1],i);
        if (i == 0){
            answer[username.length() +1] = '\0';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
char decrypt(char c, int position)
{
    if (position == 4){
         return '-'; }
    if (c > 'M'){
        c -= 17;    }
    else{
        c += 21;    }
    c ^= position;
    c ^= 2;
    return c;
}
```

If I will try to print the string `username` I will get the string and not the memory location of username. So I'm not sure what is going on..
Thanks for any help,
Or

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, try to use the `answer` variable as a `string` and not a `char*`. A string authomatically resize and realocates its internal buffer if needed.

The code could looks like this:

```
string username;
string answer;
cin >> username;
for (int i = 0; i < username.length(); i++)
{
    answer += decrypt(username[i],i+1);
}
```

Then if you want to see the content of the internal string buffer, you can use `answer.c_str ();`

Edit:

As songyuanyao said, your code uses an array of `string`. But the solution of using an array of 20 chars (`char answer [20]`) leads to a memory issue if the username has a size of 20 or more.

Comment: Its good to know that string manage its buffer, but shouldn't you add `\0` on the end?

Comment: @Smiled_One `string::c_str()` will do it for you, it will return a null-terminated character array.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly,

```
string answer[20] = "";
```

should be

```
char answer[20];
```

`string answer[20]` is array of `std::string`, not the c-style string (i.e. char[]).

Comment: @Smiled_One Everybody makes a mistake sometimes, never mind. :D

Answer (score 2):

In this code, `answer` is not a string – it is an array of 20 strings.  You probably want `char answer[20]`, or, more likely, to create a single string `answer` and append the result with `answer += character`.